# Source and Behavioral compatibility

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, java-7

I was looking at the difference between source incompatibilities and behaviorial incompatibilities but I couldn't really understand it. Can someone explain it a little please

If there is a source incompatiblity between Java 8 and Java 7 for example, does that mean that although running Java 7 compiled code with that incompatiblity in Java 8 would work just fine but if I recompile that code with Java 8, I would get an error?

Comment: java 7 bytecode can run in the java 8 jre. java 8 bytecode cannot run in the java 7 jre

Comment: If there is a source incompatiblity between Java 8 and Java 7 for example, does that mean that although running Java 7 compiled code with that incompatiblity in Java 8 would work just fine but if I recompile that code with Java 8, I would get an error?

Comment: If you target 1.8 bytecode even if you don't use any java 8 features you would be unable to run that jar in a 1.7 jre

Comment: @beresfordt OP is asking about the opposite direction.

Comment: Let's say for example  http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7144506

Comment: Definitions of the different kinds of compatibility, in the context of the JDK: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/kinds_of_compatibility

Comment: Today I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915323/5606016) which is somehow related, it might be interesting having a look at

Comment: @StuartMarks what's your view on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913775/maven-java-version-configuration-ignored-by-eclipse-idea/35915323#35915323) explanation about cross-compilation and common source/target misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although these cases are really rare, and for good reason.

One obvious example I can think of where this happened **in a planned way** was when the `enum` and `assert` keywords were introduced.

The following would've compiled with Java 1.4:

```
public void foo() {
   int enum = 42;
}
```

And would still run on any later JVM, but it wouldn't compile again with a later version of Java. Or to be more procise, it wouldn't compile without specifying the `-source 1.4` option to `javac`.

The [compiler bug you cited](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7144506) is an example of how this can happen **accidentally** (even though the sample code they provided isn't very useful, as even if you manage to compile it, at runtime it will only throw a NPE).